# php click out logged user with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session, authentication

good afternoon from gmt+8 timezone.

I had built a login/system , now I want to implement a function that will click out users , so i make a status column in the db , 
2 types of values , lock => lock , active => not lock.
I can use **crud** method to update the status and output in a table. surely i cam lock the user , and status change to **lock**, that is working fine, but the problem is the locked user still has access the to system , since the session still valid , she/he has to close the browser or their session is terminated. 
on the login page I check if user is lock then can login.

since the user still has access when the session still valid , I want to input **ajax** call the server to check the status on setInterval. 
on backend php: check if user is lock , terminate the session , give alerts box and redirect.

but the issue now is my code is not working， here are my ajax call , if I un-comment //console.log('success');, success will be kept in console.log , meaning the call is success.

```
<script>
        function getUserStatus(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ajax/ajax.php',
                data: {username: '<?php echo $_SESSION['admin_username'] ;?>' },
                success: function(response){
                    //console.log('success');
                }
            });
        }

        setInterval(function(){
            getUserStatus();
        },3000);

    </script>
```

on my ajax.php page , I make sure connection to db is working,

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        $admin_username = check_input($_POST['username']);

  if( isLocked($admin_username) ){
       session_destroy();
echo "<script>window.alert('you had been clicked out');window.location.href='../index.php';</script>";
        }

    }
```

function to check user is lock

```
function isLocked($username){
    global $connection ; 
    $query = "SELECT status FROM table where name = '$username' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    confirm($result);

    while(  $row = fetch_array($result)){
        if($row['status'] == 'locked' ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }  
    }
}
```

if i directly access ajax.php with the log user , below action is working .

```
    if( isLocked($admin_username) ){
                session_destroy();
echo "<script>window.alert('you had been clickedout');window.location.href='../index.php';</script>"; }
```

not sure what is wrong with my codes and how to fix it ?

any assistance/suggestion would be highly appreciated .

Comment: your ajax.php returns a script, have you tried to add dataType: "script", to your call ( after type: "POST", ) and remove the <script> tags in the echo?

Comment: @FatFreddy , its working , can you pls explain the logic behind ? you may write as an answer , I will accept it thanks 
by the way , are there other ways to archive it without using ajax , because it may add burden to the server.
appreciated

Comment: can I remove this ->  success: function(response){} now ? as I do all the action in the php file.

Comment: try it out ;-) i would not recomend it, i alway use a success and error or since jquery 3.0 a .fail and a .done part

Comment: an other option is not to use a setinterval or timeout , but just check in every .php  isLockedfile , will result in not to show the action on an idle user. or another option my be sockets.

Comment: thanks it sounds workable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ajax.php echos something, that may be data, a json or in your case a js script.
The ajax calls ajax/ajax.php, if the http request succeeds it enters

```
success: 
        function(response){
                        //console.log('success');
                }
```

so the variable `response` holds the output of that call to ajax/ajax.php. if you use

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ajax/ajax.php',
                dataType: "script",
                data: {username: '<?php echo $_SESSION['admin_username'] ;?>' },
                success: function(response){
                    //console.log('success');
                }
```

the value of "response" will be executed if it is a working script.(without  tags)

further information you can find here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

without dataType: "script",in the call you could do something like that:

```
function(response){
                    //console.log('success');
                    $('#somediv').html(response);
                }
```

that will insert the result in a div, if it is a well formated js script,  it will be executed.